# Error deploying Cookiecutter-Django app to Heroku

Tags: django, docker, heroku, django-3.0, cookiecutter-django

I'm working with the Django Cookiecutter boilerplate, using Docker. Everything works fine locally so now I'm trying to deploy the app to Heroku by following this guide: [Deployment on Heroku](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment-on-heroku.html). I'm using Django 3 and Rest framework. Docker for development.

After running the config commands, I push to Heroku master and get this error:

```
Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
```

Here's the trace:

```
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 273, in get_value
remote:            value = self.ENVIRON[var]
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
remote:            raise KeyError(key) from None
remote:        KeyError: 'SENDGRID_API_KEY'
remote:        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 31, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 231, in fetch_command
remote:            settings.INSTALLED_APPS
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
remote:            self._setup(name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
remote:            self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
remote:            mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:          File "/tmp/build_027dd19e3113d3ba2634e63f0f93e673/config/settings/production.py", line 128, in <module>
remote:            "SENDGRID_API_KEY": env("SENDGRID_API_KEY"),
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 123, in __call__
remote:            return self.get_value(var, cast=cast, default=default, parse_default=parse_default)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 277, in get_value
remote:            raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
remote:        django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SENDGRID_API_KEY environment variable
```

Beneath the error, I get the message to disable collect static with this command:

```
$ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

I run the command above and proceed but the next command doesn't work because Heroku can't find the manage.py file

```
heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser
```

I've searched various deployment guides online but it looks like deploying a Django app on Heroku is not as straightforward as it is on Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that the app is missing the environment variable `SENDGRID_API_KEY`. That sounds like a documentation bug, if you have a minute I would appreciate if you could please [report it](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/issues/new?template=bug.md).

Basically, the Deployment for Heroku assumes that you're using Mailgun as email service, as it ask you to run:

```
heroku addons:create mailgun:starter
```

However, you seem to have selected Sendgrid, which is an option that was introduced recently (See [PR #2435](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/pull/2435)), but this page wasn't updated accordingly.

To fix your problem, you need to add the [Sendgrid add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/sendgrid) to your app. Once added, from Heroku, you should be able to click the add-on to access your Sendgrid dashboard where you need to create an API key [as per this guide](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/api-keys/) and add it the config vars of you Heroku app, [following this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Comment: Thank you Bruno. I set the Sendgrid api key but still had the same issue so I changed the mail service to Mailgun and deployment went smoothly.